# Second js function not working

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the second function is not working?  The first function works fine, but the subsequent click outside of the submenu does not work.

```
//reveal submenu, dropdown when browser is < 613px

function revealSubmenu_web() {
    var sites = document.getElementById("sites");
    var container = document.getElementById("menu_container");

    if (window.innerWidth > 613) {
        sites.classList.toggle("show_sub");
    } else {
        sites.classList.toggle("show_sub");
        container.classList.toggle("container_height");
    }
}

//close submenu when clicked outside
window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('.submenu_web')) {
        var myDropdown = document.getElementById("sites");
        if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show_sub')) {
            myDropdown.classList.remove('show_sub');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `string.match` try `element.classList.contains`. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: try polyfill here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: `why the second function is not working` - can your browsers **developer** tools tell you what the error is